# Django python 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available database backend

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-pyodbc-azure

I'm trying to connect my Django app to microsoft sql database on apache server but I get the following error messages:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

I have installed django-pyodbc-azure and it's showing up as part of (pip freeze list):

```
Django==2.1
django-pyodbc==1.1.3
django-pyodbc-azure==2.1.0.0
pyodbc==4.0.25
```

Here is settings.py database configuration:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'name',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'host',
    'PORT': '',

    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
    },

},
```

Inside site-packages folder, it's doesn't show the actual django-pyodbc-azure folder but when i run the command (pip show django-pyodbc-azure), it shows the package location (/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages) which means it's successfully installed.

So I'm not really sure what is the problem.

Comment: It doesn't appear you're using a virtual environment, which I would highly recommend. `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/` would be the system Python version, not your virtual environment.

Comment: @FlipperPA Thanks for your reply, so If I use virtual environment and install that django-pyodbc-azure inside it will actually solve my problem?

Comment: I'm guessing that is the most likely culprit. I always use virtual environments for every Python project; it is worth learning, as it will save you lots of headaches down the road!

Comment: @FlipperPA Can I create more than one virtual environment within a project? Because I forgot the name of the first one

Comment: Yes, you absolutely can. I'd recommend checking out the Django Girls tutorial here for a bit of information on virtual environments: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/

Comment: @FlipperPA I've managed to get the name of the virtual environment, I have installed django-pyodbc-azure in it and that fixed the issue :D Thank you

Comment: I know you've solved this @Mack but I wanted to stress using virtual environments - they allow you to isolate them so you can keep packages all based on what's needed per project/application. Combining those with a `requirements.txt` file is the best thing you can do for any python/django application!

Comment: I'd love to understand why using a virtual environment fixed this problem, as this doesn't seem logical to me. I get that they are always a great idea, but how can the problem have been solved by just using one? Keep safe, guys...

Comment: @Jonathan, I think the answer is "cruft" or "clutter". If you don't use a virtual environment, you will inevitably run into namespace collisions, at which point you have no idea which library you're actually pulling modules in from. This definitely seems to be the case for this issue.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. Somehow the installation of the azure-backend messed up my project.

I removed the django-pyodbc-azure and django-mssql-backend packages since they only support the older django versions. Afterwards i installed the mssql backend from https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django

```
pip uninstall django-pyodbc-azure
pip uninstall django-mssql-backend
pip install mssql-django
```

Then i configured the DB to use `'ENGINE': 'mssql'`

After this i was able to connect to our MSSQL DB **using Django 3.2 and newer Versions!**

Comment: Still works, 4/5/2023

Comment: Maybe @Mack should mark this post as solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install `pip install django-pyodbc-azure`

https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/

I had the same problem and using that it worked.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'Name_database',
        'USER': 'User',
        'PASSWORD': 'Password',
        'HOST': 'IP',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Appears that django-pyodbc-azure requires Django 2.*, just a heads up.

Comment: is there another solution using Django 3.0+?

Answer (score 2):

Use [mssql-django](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django) with versions of [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/) `>=2.2 and <4.1`.
As of today current version of `mssql-django==1.1.3` supports Django versions `>=2.2 and <4.1` https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django/blob/c0476cf4e49ab3dcbbab37ccb3e558216841b6dc/setup.py#L41

To use older versions of Django use `django-pyodbc-azure`.
The support for `Django==1.8` was added by https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django/tree/0b0cee7030795682b37da36a48ebb065a3faa00e  and removed by this: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django/tree/204d1fc0a4ade0ebe3e1df07a943c03b5ab5cf33.

To use `Django==1.8.x` use `pip install "django-pyodbc-azure<1.9"` where it Supports Microsoft SQL Server 2005, 2008/2008R2, 2012, 2014 and
Azure SQL Database: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django/commit/204d1fc0a4ade0ebe3e1df07a943c03b5ab5cf33#diff-7b3ed02bc73dc06b7db906cf97aa91dec2b2eb21f2d92bc5caa761df5bbc168fR241

**Note:**
if you are using older version of Django (<2.0.0), installing `mssql-django` will force install/upgrade to newer supported version of django as part of its requirement.
One may need to go through readme.md, setup.py files to know the supported versions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72225169/connecting-to-mssql-from-django-1-8-on-ubuntu) solution. In the comment there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use python:3.9.13-slim-buster,
Django 3.2
And install mssql-django

```
FROM python:3.9.13-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ADD odbcinst.ini /etc/
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl gnupg
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev tdsodbc freetds-common freetds-bin freetds-dev postgresql python-scipy python-numpy python-pandas
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools msodbcsql17
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install mssql-django
RUN mkdir /code
COPY . /code/
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
```

Create file odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

requirements.txt

```
Django==3.2
django-environ==0.4.5
# psycopg2>=2.8.6,<2.9
uWSGI>=2.0.19.1,<2.1
Pillow >= 9.0.0,<10.0.0
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST_SITO'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME_SITO'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER_SITO'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS_SITO'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT_SITO'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'FreeTDS',
            'unicode_results': True,
            'host_is_server': True,
            'driver_supports_utf8': True,
            'extra_params': 'tds_version=7.4',
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

installing django==3.0 would be helpful