# Connecting to MSSQL from django 1.8 on Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, django, django-1.8, django-mssql, django-mssql-backend

I need to connect to `MSSQL` database from `Django 1.8` and preserve `Django 1.8` (not upgrade to newer version od Django).

I installed
`pip install django-mssql` . `ENGINE` in `settings.py` is `sqlserver_ado`.

It ended with error message
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pythoncom`.

According to [this](https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#dependencies) page I see that `django-mssql` needs `PyWin32`.

So I returned back to my snapshot in virtual machine and tried it with
`pip install django-mssql-backend` and changed the `ENGINE` in `settings.py` to `sql_server.pyodbc`
Now I have error message
`sql_server.pyodbc isn't an available database backend.`

So I returned back to my snapshot in virtual machine and tried it with `pip install mssql-django` and `ENGINE` is `mssql`. This upgraded `Django` to `3.4.1`.

So I returned to my snapshot of virtual machine.
How can I connect to `MSSQL` from `Django 1.8` without upgrading `Django`? Or is it impossible? Why?

`Django 1.8` is running on `Ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: What version of python have you installed? Try pip3 install django-mssql

Comment: In my virtual environment I use `Python 3.6.9`.

Comment: Try using: https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/ (Will only work with Python 2) **Note:** Django 1.8 is an insecure, unsupported version. Please consider upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: @LordPokerFace It ends with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pythoncom`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat This helped. Thanks a lot. You can write it as an answer. And `ENGINE` must be `django_pyodbc`

Comment: Use pip3 for install the needed modules.